# after splash i added addListenerOnButtonClick(); in mainactivity.java then app crashes

Tags: android, crash, screen, splash-screen, android-appcompat

**mainactivity.java**

package com.example.newsplash;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle; import android.view.View; import android.widget.Button; import android.widget.CheckBox; import android.widget.Toast;

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    CheckBox Chapathi, Dosai, Biriyani, Coffee;
    Button order;`enter code here`
    @Override

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        addListenerOnButtonClick();

    }



    public void addListenerOnButtonClick() {
        Chapathi = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.Chapathi);
        Biriyani = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.Biriyani);
        Dosai = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.Dosai);
        Coffee = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.Coffee);


        order.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick (View view)
            {
                int totalamount = 0;
                StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
                result.append("Selected Items:");
                if (Chapathi.isChecked()) {
                    result.append("\nChapathi 10RS");
                    totalamount += 10;

                }
                if (Biriyani.isChecked()) {
                    result.append("\nBiriyani is 100RS");
                    totalamount += 100;
                }
                if (Dosai.isChecked()) {
                    result.append("\nDosai is 10RS");
                    totalamount += 10;

                }
                if (Coffee.isChecked()) {
                    result.append("\n Coffee is 10RS");
                    totalamount += 10;
                }
                result.append(("\nTotal"+totalamount + "RS"));
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }


        });

    }

}
```

**logcat** 2020-11-05 00:33:48.523 27490-27966/com.example.newsplash D/mmscene: getHint applicationScene=com.example.newsplash,idx=0 none 2020-11-05 00:33:48.577 27490-27490/com.example.newsplash I/Choreographer: Skipped 7 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread. 2020-11-05 00:33:51.378 27490-27490/com.example.newsplash W/ActivityThread: handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy@3268ab0 2020-11-05 00:33:51.928 27490-27490/com.example.newsplash D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM 2020-11-05 00:33:51.938 27490-27490/com.example.newsplash E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.newsplash, PID: 27490
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.newsplash/com.example.newsplash.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3146)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3296)
at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:114)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:74)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1994)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:226)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:500)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:913)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
at com.example.newsplash.MainActivity.addListenerOnButtonClick(MainActivity.java:36)
at com.example.newsplash.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:23)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7337)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7328)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1272)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3126)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3296) 
at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) 
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:114) 
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:74) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1994) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:226) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**yes now worked . thank  you **
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
CheckBox Chapathi, Dosai, Biriyani, Coffee;
Button button;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    addListenerOnButtonClick();
}

public void addListenerOnButtonClick() {
    Chapathi = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.Chapathi);
    Biriyani = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.Biriyani);
    Dosai = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.Dosai);
    Coffee = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.Coffee);


    
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.order);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick (View view)
        {
            int totalamount = 0;
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
            result.append("Selected Items:");
            if (Chapathi.isChecked()) {
                result.append("\nChapathi 10RS");
                totalamount += 10;

            }
            if (Biriyani.isChecked()) {
                result.append("\nBiriyani is 100RS");
                totalamount += 100;
            }
            if (Dosai.isChecked()) {
                result.append("\nDosai is 10RS");
                totalamount += 10;

            }
            if (Coffee.isChecked()) {
                result.append("\n Coffee is 10RS");
                totalamount += 10;
            }
            result.append(("\nTotal"+totalamount + "RS"));
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }


    });

}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

1. Your code

You create a variable `Button order` but you never initialize it.
Then, on an uninitialized button, you're calling `.setOnClickListener` which obviously cannot be done.

2. Your stack trace:

   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference

Solution is to use `findViewById` for `order` and get an actual button reference after which you can use `.setOnClickListener`

Comment: @btmme If the answer has helped you, please mark it as `accepted answer` with the check mark to the left of my answer. It's much appreciated.

Comment: ok bro. done . thank you for sharing your time &knowledge .